# How to disable a gameObject such that it does not open again when starting the game again

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I made a game in which I am asking the name of the user and then displaying it on clicking the "next" button.
But it always asks the name whenever I open the game.
I want to do something so that it asks the name and then save it and disable the previous gameObject through which it was asking three name.
So whenever I open the game it only displays my name and not ask my name.

Comment: how are you saving the name? when you run the game again if name is set, disable the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Playerprefs to save the name locally.After clicking on next button, save the name using Playerprefs as shown below

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Name", m_PlayerName);
```

At the start of the game you can check if the name is set locally and based on that you can disable the gameobject as you need. You can check if the name key exists locally as shown below :

```
hasName = PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Name");
```

Returns true if key exists in the preference.

Thus if it returns true you can disable the gameobject and not ask the name again.
However if it returns false, it means name hasn't been entered by the user yet so you can show the page/gameobject and ask user to enter their name